# How to automaticly assigned a entry a unique id for use in a relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

A basic overview of my app. There is currently two models. A jobs model and a clients model. Both models have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship as I intended to allow the user to create a client entry and then assign them one or many jobs.

Here are both of my models.

Clients -

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_and_belongs_to_many :job
end
```

Jobs -

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :client
end
```

I have been doing some research and I think im right in thinking that the relationship needs a foreign key to function so have added a `client_id` column & a `job_id` column to my database.

The clients page is currently working and here is my controller for that.

```
class ClientsController < ApplicationController

        def index
          @clients = Client.all

          respond_to do |format|
            format.html # index.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @clients }
          end
        end

        # GET /Clients/1
        # GET /Clients/1.json
        def show
          @clients = Client.find(params[:id])

          respond_to do |format|
            format.html # show.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @clients }
          end
        end

        # GET /Clients/new
        # GET /Clients/new.json
        def new
          @clients = Client.new

          respond_to do |format|
            format.html # new.html.erb
            format.json { render json: @clients }
          end
        end

        # GET /Clients/1/edit
        def edit
          @clients = Client.find(params[:id])
        end


        def create
          @clients = Client.new(params[:client])

          respond_to do |format|
            if @clients.save
              format.html { redirect_to @clients, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
              format.json { render json: @clients, status: :created, location: @clients }
            else
              format.html { render action: "new" }
              format.json { render json: @clients.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end

        # PUT /Clients/1
        # PUT /Clients/1.json
        def update
          @clients = Client.find(params[:id])

          respond_to do |format|
            if @clients.update_attributes(params[:client])
              format.html { redirect_to @clients, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
              format.json { head :no_content }
            else
              format.html { render action: "edit" }
              format.json { render json: @clients.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
          end
        end

        # DELETE /Clients/1
        # DELETE /Clients/1.json
        def destroy
          @clients = Client.find(params[:id])
          @clients.destroy

          respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to :clients , notice: 'Client was successfully removed.'}
            format.json { head :no_content }
          end
        end

        def details
            @clients = Client.find_by_id(params[:id])
            @jobs = Client.job
        end
      end
```

And here's what I currently have for my jobs controller.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @jobs = Job.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def new
    @jobs = Job.new 

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml { render :xml => @job }
    end
  end

  def create
    @jobs = Job.new(params[:job])
    @cients = Client.find = Client.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @jobs.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@jobs,
                      :notice => 'Job was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @jobs,
                      :status => :created, :location => @Job }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @jobs.errors,
                      :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In my jobs form I was given thr following code which added a drop down with all the created clients.

```
<%= select("job", "client_id", Client.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'None'})%>
```

When I press save though. I recieve the following error.

```
unknown attribute: client_id

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:22:in `new'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:22:in `create'
```

I assume this is because I need to define a way of finding the client_id in my job creation as well as specifying one in my client creation.

This is my first rails app though so im not quite sure how.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `jobs` table doesn't have a `client_id`, nor should it. You need to create a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to facilitate a many-to-many relationship. It should be called `clients_jobs` and contain an integer `client_id` and `job_id`.

There is a **lot** more wrong here. Here are just the things I caught at a casual glance:

1. This line:

   ```
   @cients = Client.find = Client.find(params[:id])
   ```

   should be:

   ```
   @cients = Client.find(params[:id])
   ```
2. Pluralization is important in Rails. A client doesn't have many "job". It has many job**s**. Your models should reflect this:

   ```
   class Client < ActiveRecord::Base 
     has_and_belongs_to_many :jobs
   end

   class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
   end
   ```
3. You'll need to create a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) via a migration, which is where your foreign keys will exist:

   ```
   $ rails g migration AddClientsJobsTable
   ```
4. In `index` and `new`, you first create `@jobs = Job.new` and then you render it via `:xml => @job`. Again, pluralization is important. You need `@job = Job.new`. You have the same problem in `create`, except you've dropped the 's' **and** capitalized the 'J': `:location => @Job }` You can't *do* that in programming. Case and spelling both matter.
5. `Job.find(:all)` or `Client.all`: Pick one. Don't mix `find :all` and `.all`.
6. `@clients = Client.find(params[:id])`. You're finding a *single* specific Client, not a collection of clients. Your variable should be called `@client`. This is not an *error*, but it is seriously ugly.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This is my first Rails app/attempt at 'backend' coding so excuse any mistakes :)
Only question. I ssume I have to assign a client IT from the junction table?
How do I do that?

Comment: You won't have to interact with the junction table in any way; Rails will manage it for you. All you'll have to do is either assign a client to a job (`@job.clients << @client`) or assign a job to a client (`@client.job = @job`).

Comment: When I try and create a job im getting `unknown attribute: client_id

app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:23:in `new'
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:23:in `create` `

Answer (score 1):

pluralize your jobs and clients in your associations. I.E

```
has_many_and_belongs_to :jobs
has_many_and_belongs_to :clients
```

And if you do not use the alternative to this many-to-many associations with the ActiveRecord :through method (the alternative to HMABT) You must create the join table yourself which is a table of job_id's and client_id's.